# How to use asp.net routing C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anybody help me with this link?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAuthService _auth;
    public AuthController(IAuthService auth)
    {
        _auth = auth;
    }

    [HttpGet("getuser/{sessionGuid}")]
    public IActionResult Get(Guid sessionGuid)
    {
        \\code         
    }
```

How should the URL be written in order to get to `public IActionResult Get(Guid sessionGuid)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Route("api/[controller]")` attribute you have given your Controller tells the framework to use the name of the Controller as part of the route.

In this case you have an `AuthController` so all the routes in this Controller will be prefixed with `api/auth/`.

Additionally you've specified to the framework to map you `Get` method to the `"getuser/{sessionGuid}"` route (where `sessionGuid` is some `Guid`).

Putting this together the URL you need to call is `api/auth/getuser/{sessionGuid}`.

All of this needs to be prefixed by the hostname etc. `http://localhost:5000/` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Move your route onto the function, and configure it however you'd like.

In my example, it would be: HTTP GET : http://api.com/my/ur/with/as/many/slashses/as/I/want/52

```
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAuthService _auth;
    public AuthController(IAuthService auth)
    {
        _auth = auth;
    }

    [Route("my/url/with/as/many/slashes/as/I/want/{sessionGuid}")]
    [HttpGet("{sessionGuid}")]
    public IActionResult Get(Guid sessionGuid)
    {
        \\code         
    }
}
```